# How to understand the principles of recursions in practice?

Tags: java, recursion

I started learning recursions and it seemed like I understood how they work. But as soon as I tried to pass a quiz, I found that I actually didn't. Here is some code from latest task I tried to pass. Here I tried to find a factorial. To do this I have to multiply all the numbers from 1 till the N number.

Here is some code:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(1);
}

private static void f(int n) {
    System.out.print(n);
    if (n < 7) {
        f(2 * n);
    }
}
}
```

I tried to multiply these nums and to multiply the product for 2. But I failed when saw that the result isn't 5040. The actual output is 1248. Maybe I was doing actions in wrong order?

Comment: I downvoted, because, even though the question shows attempt, it doesn't show research. There are tons of materials about recursion throughout the internet; most of them also explain the factorial.

Comment: Learn concepts first. Look here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/

Comment: What you're doing qualifies as recursion but not as calculating the factorial. A factorial of N (written as N!) is N x (N-1) x .... x 2 x 1 (so factor of 5 is 5! = 5x4x3x2x1 = 120). You're just stacking numbers together which is not finding the factorial. As the others pointed, please learn more about factorials in general before implementing it in code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look how to multiply numbers from `1` to `n` using recurrency:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long result = mulFromOneTo(30);
}

private long mulFromOneTo(int number) {
   if (number == 1) {
       return 1;
   } else {
       return number * mulFromOneTo(number - 1);
   }
}
```

I don't want to give you completely prepared source code - but I hope it'll help you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Andrezej's answer is a good top-down approach. Let's have a look at why your code doesn't work:

If we summarize what `f` is doing, it prints `n` and it will call itself recursively with `2 * n` when `n` is less than 7.

So in your example, you first call `f(1)` so it prints `1` and calls `f(2)`, which prints `2` and calls `f(4)`, prints `4`, calls `f(8)`, prints `8` and stop.

So your function is not printing the number `1248`, but it's printing `1`, `2`, `4` and `8` independently.

The total computation done by your recursive function is `(2 * (2 * (2 * 1)))`